# Error showing when downloading ubuntu gnome 16.04lts.iso issuing about authorization and yet the file is downloding

Tags: gnome, system-installation, iso, transmission

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. So I was thinking of switching to ubuntu gnome. I tried to download file from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/GetUbuntuGNOME)

Now, I have downloaded the Ubuntu gnome iso file via the transmission bit torrent client.

The file starts downloading itself saying `downloading error: requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker` like this image is showing

[image]

- What is causing this problem
- Should i burn this iso file in usb stick to reboot/for further installation?

Comment: The error is usually caused by Transmission trying to verify the torrent against an unsupported tracker, it should be nothing to be concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the version 16.04.1 instead of 16.04 won't have that issue.You may find that [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BitTorrent)
if you do not find the iso go directly [here.](http://torrent.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/xenial/release/desktop/)

"With a new version out Canonical obviously don't want the old version (without the latest bug fixes) propagated any more. The only way to stop a torrent in the wild is to stop the tracker. So that is what they did." 
[source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1555965)